# Елемент выплывает под (CSS, Hover). При нажатии кнопки мыши исчезает блок, какбудто я убераю мышку

Tags: html, css, hover

Есть выплывающий блок (выплывает по `CSS`, методом hover)
Иногда (не всегда), при нажатии кнопки мыши, в блоке (есть разные елементы) - блок исчезает какбудто я убираю мышку.

Kто то встречал подобный баг?

```css
#center_menu_bar {
  float: right;
  width: 1.5%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#center_menu_bar>#center_menu {
  display: none;
}

#center_menu_bar:hover>#center_menu {
  display: inline-block;
}

#center_menu_bar:hover>img {
  display: none;
}

#center_menu_bar:hover {
  width: 20%;
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(108, 140, 213, 0.2);
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(240, 249, 255, 0.3) 0%, rgba(203, 235, 255, 0.3) 25%, rgba(161, 219, 255, 0.3) 100%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(240, 249, 255, 0.3) 0%, rgba(203, 235, 255, 0.3) 25%, rgba(161, 219, 255, 0.3) 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(240, 249, 255, 0.3) 0%, rgba(203, 235, 255, 0.3) 25%, rgba(161, 219, 255, 0.3) 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4df0f9ff', endColorstr='#4da1dbff', GradientType=1);
  /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}

#center_menu_bar img {
  float: left;
  height: 2%;
  margin: 260px 0;
}

#center_menu {
  width: 98%;
  float: left;
}

.center_menu_item {
  width: 90%;
  max-height: 14px;
  margin: 2% auto 0;
  padding: 2% 3%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(240, 249, 255, 0.3) 0%, rgba(203, 235, 255, 0.3) 25%, rgba(161, 219, 255, 0.3) 100%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(240, 249, 255, 0.3) 0%, rgba(203, 235, 255, 0.3) 25%, rgba(161, 219, 255, 0.3) 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(240, 249, 255, 0.3) 0%, rgba(203, 235, 255, 0.3) 25%, rgba(161, 219, 255, 0.3) 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4df0f9ff', endColorstr='#4da1dbff', GradientType=1);
  /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}

.center_menu_item:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid rgba(108, 140, 213, 0.1);
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.center_menu_item:hover>.open {
  background-image: url("../images/icons/view.png");
}

.center_menu_item:hover>.close {
  background-image: url("../images/icons/hide.png");
}

.center_menu_item_open {
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 2% auto 0;
  padding: 2% 3%;
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(240, 249, 255, 0.5) 0%, rgba(203, 235, 255, 0.5) 25%, rgba(161, 219, 255, 0.5) 100%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(240, 249, 255, 0.5) 0%, rgba(203, 235, 255, 0.5) 25%, rgba(161, 219, 255, 0.5) 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(240, 249, 255, 0.5) 0%, rgba(203, 235, 255, 0.5) 25%, rgba(161, 219, 255, 0.5) 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4df0f9ff', endColorstr='#4da1dbff', GradientType=1);
  /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}

.center_menu_item_open:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid rgba(108, 140, 213, 0.1);
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.open {
  float: right;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  margin: -16px 5px 0 0;
  background-image: url("../images/icons/hide.png");
  background-size: cover;
}

.open:hover {
  background-image: url("../images/icons/view.png");
}

.close {
  float: right;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  margin: -16px 5px 0 0;
  background-image: url("../images/icons/view.png");
  background-size: cover;
}

.close:hover {
  background-image: url("../images/icons/hide.png");
}

.fields_item {
  width: 86%;
  margin: 4px auto;
}

.swich_on {
  float: left;
  width: 24px;
  height: 18px;
  margin: 0 4% 0 0;
  background: url("../images/icons/switch.png");
  background-size: cover;
}

.swich_on:hover {
  float: left;
  width: 24px;
  height: 18px;
  margin: 0% 4% 0 0;
  background: url(../images/icons/switch-1.png);
  background-size: cover;
}

.swich_off {
  float: left;
  width: 24px;
  height: 18px;
  margin: 0 4% 0 0;
  background: url("../images/icons/switch-1.png");
  background-size: cover;
}

.swich_off:hover {
  float: left;
  width: 24px;
  height: 18px;
  margin: 0 4% 0 0;
  background: url("../images/icons/switch.png");
  background-size: cover;
}

.center_menu_button {
  float: left;
  width: 44%;
  margin: 2% 0 5% 2%;
  padding: 2% 1.3%;
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(240, 249, 255, 0.3) 0%, rgba(203, 235, 255, 0.3) 25%, rgba(161, 219, 255, 0.3) 100%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(240, 249, 255, 0.3) 0%, rgba(203, 235, 255, 0.3) 25%, rgba(161, 219, 255, 0.3) 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(240, 249, 255, 0.3) 0%, rgba(203, 235, 255, 0.3) 25%, rgba(161, 219, 255, 0.3) 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4df0f9ff', endColorstr='#4da1dbff', GradientType=1);
  /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}

.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 96%;
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #412C84;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #412C84;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#order_summ_multislider {}

@supports (--css: variables) {
  input[type="range"].multirange {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  input[type="range"].multirange.original {
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
  }
  input[type="range"].multirange.original::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #412C84;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  input[type="range"].multirange.original::-moz-range-thumb {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #412C84;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: scale(1);
    /* FF doesn't apply position it seems */
    z-index: 1;
  }
  input[type="range"].multirange::-moz-range-track {
    border-color: transparent;
    /* needed to switch FF to "styleable" control */
  }
  input[type="range"].multirange.ghost {
    margin: -21px auto 0 40px;
    position: relative;
    background: var(--track-background);
    --track-background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent var(--low), var(--range-color) 0, var(--range-color) var(--high), transparent 0) no-repeat 0 45% / 100% 40%;
    --range-color: #412C84;
  }
  input[type="range"].multirange.ghost::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    background: var(--track-background);
  }
  input[type="range"].multirange.ghost::-moz-range-track {
    background: var(--track-background);
  }
}

.center_menu_button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #412C84;
  border: 1px solid rgba(108, 140, 213, 0.1);
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="center_side" class="side_bar">
  <div id="center_menu_bar">
    <div id="center_menu">
      <div class="menu_item center_menu_item">
        <div class="center_menu_item_name">Fields</div>
        <div class="show_hide open"></div>

        <div id="c1" class="fields_item">
          <div class="swich_on"></div>c1</div>
        <div id="c2" class="fields_item">
          <div class="swich_on"></div>c2</div>
        <div id="c3" class="fields_item">
          <div class="swich_off"></div>c3</div>
        <div id="c4" class="fields_item">
          <div class="swich_off"></div>c4</div>
        <div id="c5" class="fields_item">
          <div class="swich_on"></div>c5</div>
        <div id="c6" class="fields_item">
          <div class="swich_off"></div>c6</div>
        <div id="c7" class="fields_item">
          <div class="swich_on"></div>c7</div>
        <div id="c8" class="fields_item">
          <div class="swich_on"></div>c8</div>
        <div id="c9" class="fields_item">
          <div class="swich_off"></div>c9</div>
        <div id="c10" class="fields_item">
          <div class="swich_on"></div>c10</div>
        <div id="c11" class="fields_item">
          <div class="swich_on"></div>c11</div>
        <div id="c12" class="fields_item">
          <div class="swich_on"></div>c12</div>

      </div>
      <div class="menu_item center_menu_item">
        <div class="center_menu_item_name">Orders count: <span id="order_count_value"></span></div>
        <div class="show_hide open"></div>
        <div class="slidecontainer"><input type="range" min="10" max="1000" value="20" class="slider" id="order_count" step="10" /></div>

      </div>
      <div class="menu_item center_menu_item">
        <div class="center_menu_item_name">Orders filters</div>
        <div class="show_hide open"></div>
        <div id="brand"></div>
        <div id="category"></div>
        <div id="subcategory"></div>
        <div id="subcategory2"></div>
        <div id="subcategory3"></div>

        <div id="order_summ">Order summ: <span id="order_summ_value"></span></div>
        <div class="swich_on"></div>
        <input type="range" multiple value="100,1300" min="100" max="1300" step="50" id="order_summ_multislider" />


        <div id="order_average_summ">Order average summ: <span id="order_average_summ_value"></span></div>
        <div class="swich_off"></div>
        <input type="range" multiple value="100,1300" min="100" max="1300" step="50" id="order_average_summ_multislider" />

        <div id="cross_summ">Cross summ: <span id="cross_summ_value"></span></div>
        <div class="swich_off"></div>
        <input type="range" multiple value="100,1300" min="100" max="1300" step="50" id="cross_summ_multislider" />

        <div id="cross_average_summ">Cross average summ: <span id="cross_average_summ_value"></span></div>

        <div class="swich_off"></div>
        <input type="range" multiple value="100,1300" min="100" max="1300" step="50" id="cross_average_summ_multislider" />

      </div>
      <div class="menu_item center_menu_item">
        <div class="center_menu_item_name">Date Filters</div>
        <div class="show_hide open"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="menu_item center_menu_item">
        <div class="center_menu_item_name">Worker Filters</div>
        <div class="show_hide open"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="menu_item center_menu_item">
        <div class="center_menu_item_name">Product Filters</div>
        <div class="show_hide open"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="menu_item center_menu_item">
        <div class="center_menu_item_name">Delivery Filters</div>
        <div class="show_hide open"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="search" class="center_menu_button">Search</div>
      <div id="default" class="center_menu_button">Default filters</div>

    </div>
    <!--img src="style/images/soft/center_menu_bar_arrow.png" / -->
    <img src="//picsum.photos/200/300" alt="picsum.photos" title="placeholder picsum.photos">

  </div>
  <div id="center_header">Orders from: 00-00-0000 to: 00-00-0000 and with status "xxxxxxx"</div>


</div>
```

Comment: вангую : вы говорите о теге `a` ? если нет то код покажите

Comment: Максим спасибо что откликнулся на мою просьбу

Нет это не тэг а - это DIV
Сразу не добавил код, так как он огромный... и не знаю какие части важны, но всётаки сделал првку и добавил код...

Буду благодарен за помощь, и оценку кода.

Comment: ммм... я навёл на правый верхний угол  и меню показалось , о какой ошибке вы говорите ?

Comment: Попробуй в открытый меню, кликнуть раз 10 - 20 не сразу (имитируй клики на разные кнопки).... иногда при клике меню закрывается

Comment: раз 50 нажал - ни чего не пропадает - да и собственно по ссылке нужен всего один клик

Comment: можно с тобой связатся по вайберу?

Comment: в личке емайл - пиши